# Fixing syntax errors in lighttpd.conf?

Tags: configuration, lighttpd, syntax, lua

lighttpd newbie here...

We're trying to set up lighttpd to host a local django app, kiosk-style. We intend to use wsgi for this, but we're having trouble figuring out the syntax for lighttpd's config file -- examples pulled straight from lighttpd docs are throwing syntax errors!

It seems there are two syntaxes in play:

- One has semicolons, and function calls seem to work. Examples of this style can be found [here](http://doc.lighttpd.net/lighttpd2/mod_core.lua.html) and [here](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd2/wiki/Howto_WSGI). Keywords like `module_load` and `docroot` seem to be valid. The following lines, placed at the top of /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf, crash on startup with a syntax error:

```
  setup { 
          module_load ( "mod_expire", "mod_fastcgi", "mod_vhost", "mod_lua" );
          lua.plugin "core.lua";
  }
```

or

```
core.wsgi ( "", {fastcgi: "/var/run/lighttpd/kiosk.sock"} )
```

- The other style seems more straightforward, and lines up with the official [Configuration File Syntax](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration), as seen [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/entry/branches/lighttpd-1.4.x/doc/config/lighttpd.conf). There are no line-ending semicolons, and function calls (other than assignment) do not seem to work. This format reads more like the config-file-with-conditionals format described in the documentation, and the keyword equivalent for `server.document-root` ("`docroot`") does not seem to work here.

What is going on? Why are there two seperate configuration syntaxes? One style seems to be lua (which I'm not very familiar with...) How are they used? When is it best to use which?

I've tried Googling this, but it is difficult to search for. Lots of generic or app-specific results, with, seemingly none naming the paths of the files they show.

Comment: Are you using Ligthhtpd 2 or 1.4?

Comment: 1.4. Seems the other syntax is for 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer turns out to be the difference in syntax between version 2 (currently in beta) and 1.4. 1.4 has the non-semicolons, 2 has the semincolons